# How can we show that $X_A \cong T_e(Y_B)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules

I am reading the book [Elements of representation theory of associative algebras 1](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/Elements_of_the_Representation_Theory_of.html?id=ayNHpi3tYhQC). On Line 7 of page 37 (I attached this page below), it is said that $X_A \cong T_e(Y_B)$ since the diagram above line 7 is commutative and has exact rows. I think that if there is a homormophism from $X_A$ to $T_e(Y_B)$, then by The Five Lemma, we have $X_A \cong T_e(Y_B)$. But How can we show that there is a homormophism from $X_A$ to $T_e(Y_B)$? Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the universal property of the cokernel. We have that $X$ is the cokernel of the map $P_1\to P_0$ by definition. 
Now by commutativity of the diagram the composition of the maps $P_1\to P_0\to T_e(P_0e)\to T_e(Y_B)$ is zero. Hence there is a map $X\to T_e(Y_B)$ such that the diagram commutes.